# Pagination to show 5 pages and hide rest of the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I was trying to design a result display page with pagination. I can either display all the pages or 5 pages. I want to display 5 pages progressively.

[image]

The problem with this code is that instead, it displays all the pages. If there are 12 pages, it displays 12 buttons.

```
var length = response.length;
console.log(length);
function pagination(length){
    var size = Math.ceil(length/10);
    
    var pageDiv = $('.pagination');
    var pageDivData = "";
    pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='firstPage' class='firstPage'>&laquo;</a>";
    var stepSize = 5;
    var stepCount = Math.ceil(size/stepSize);
    console.log(stepCount);
    for(var step = 1; step<stepCount; step++){
        for(var i=id; i<=stepSize; i++){
            if(id == i){
                pageDivData +="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo active' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>";
            }else{
                pageDivData +="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>";
            }
        }
        stepSize++;
    }
    pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>...</a>";
    pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo id='"+size+"'>"+(size)+"</a>";
    if(id!=size){
        pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='lastPage'>&raquo;</a>";
    }
    pageDiv.html(pageDivData);
}
pagination(length);
```

Comment: Can you please share your html code as well.

Comment: Nothing much in HTML its just one empty tag since I am creating all the links dynamically

  <div class="pagination" style="float:right"></div>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was to make many ajax calls as per the requirements. The solution came as different parts

Answer (score 2):

Here you want to show 5 pages at a time.
So for 5 pages you are storing the value in the variable called **stepSize** So you need to keep it at 5 only.

You are incrementing the value of stepSize in every step you should not increment it keep it 5 only.

I do not get the purpose of your first for loop. What does stepCount do,why is it necessary.

So can simply edit your code with the below code:

```
var length = response.length;
    console.log(length);
    function pagination(length){
        var size = Math.ceil(length/10);
        
        var pageDiv = $('.pagination');
        var pageDivData = "";
        pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='firstPage' class='firstPage'>&laquo;</a>";
        var stepSize = 5;
            for(var i=id; i<=stepSize; i++){
                if(id == i){
                    pageDivData +="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo active' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>";
                }else{
                    pageDivData +="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>";
                }
        }
        pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>...</a>";
        pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='pageNo id='"+size+"'>"+(size)+"</a>";
        if(id!=size){
            pageDivData += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='lastPage'>&raquo;</a>";
        }
        pageDiv.html(pageDivData);
    }
pagination(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in above code. by using this code user can display next 4 (if available) pages, previous 4 (if available) and current page.

First page link and previous page links same as Last page and next page links.

So total 9 pages are display at a time and 4 extra links as well.

That code is working in React JS

```
import React from 'react';
import * as GlobalConfig from '../../providers/globals/config';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Pagenation(props) {

    const loadPage = (page) => {
        props.loadPage(page);
    };

    const totalEntries = props.paginationObj.totalEntries;
    const totalPage = props.paginationObj.totalPage;
    const currentPage = props.paginationObj.currentPage;
    const nextPage = props.paginationObj.nextPage;
    const perPage = GlobalConfig.perPage;
    const start = (props.paginationObj.skipEntries + 1);
    const end = ((props.paginationObj.skipEntries + perPage) < totalEntries) ? (props.paginationObj.skipEntries + perPage) : totalEntries;

    const PagesLink = () => {

        let pages = [];

        // first & next page links
        pages.push(
            <li key={'first'} onClick={(e) => loadPage(1)} className={(currentPage === 1) ? 'paginate_button page-item previous disabled' : 'paginate_button page-item previous'}>
                <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="0" className="page-link">&lt;&lt; First</Link>
            </li>
        );
        pages.push(
            <li key={'previous'} onClick={(e) => loadPage(((currentPage - 1) < 1) ? 1 : currentPage - 1)} className={(currentPage === 1) ? 'paginate_button page-item previous disabled' : 'paginate_button page-item previous'}>
                <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="0" className="page-link">&lt; Previous</Link>
            </li>
        );

        // display previous pages links
        let previousLinks = currentPage - 4;
        for (let i = previousLinks; i <= currentPage; i++) {
            if (i < currentPage && i > 0) {
                pages.push(
                    <li key={i} onClick={(e) => loadPage(i)} className={(currentPage === i) ? 'paginate_button page-item active' : 'paginate_button page-item'}>
                        <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="1" className="page-link">{i}</Link>
                    </li>
                );
            }
        }

        // display next pages links
        let nextLinks = (currentPage < totalPage) ? (currentPage + 4) : currentPage;
        for (let i = currentPage; i <= nextLinks; i++) {
            if (i <= totalPage) {
                pages.push(
                    <li key={i} onClick={(e) => loadPage(i)} className={(currentPage === i) ? 'paginate_button page-item active' : 'paginate_button page-item'}>
                        <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="1" className="page-link">{i}</Link>
                    </li>
                );
            }
        }

        // next & last page links 
        pages.push(
            <li key={'next'} onClick={(e) => loadPage(((currentPage + 1) > totalPage) ? totalPage : currentPage + 1)} className={(nextPage) ? 'paginate_button page-item next' : 'paginate_button page-item next disabled'}>
                <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="2" className="page-link">Next &gt;</Link>
            </li>
        );
        pages.push(
            <li key={'last'} onClick={(e) => loadPage(totalPage)} className={(nextPage) ? 'paginate_button page-item next' : 'paginate_button page-item next disabled'}>
                <Link to="#" aria-controls="listingTable" data-dt-idx="2" className="page-link">Last &gt;&gt;</Link>
            </li>
        );

        return pages;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {totalEntries > 0 &&
                <div className="pagenation-foot d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

                    <div className="totlecountpage"> <span id="displayed-record">Showing {start}-{end}</span> of {totalEntries} entries</div>

                    <div className="countingpaging">
                        <div className="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="listingTable_paginate">
                            <ul className="pagination">

                                <PagesLink />

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Pagenation;
```

[image]